# What is the default FORMAT string of printf in bash?

Tags: bash, format, printf, base32

I am trying to write a script to calculate base32 strings out of provided ByteString values which I get as key value pairs. The ByteString makes use of octal escape sequences AND backslash escape sequences.

Consider this script:

```sh
#! /bin/bash

LINE='  bytes: "LaPaLaPa\363\""'

echo $LINE

K="${LINE%%: *}"
V="${LINE#*: }"
V="${V#\"}"
V="${V%\"}"      
K="${K^^}"

echo "KV='${K}'='${V}'"

FOO="$(printf "%b" "${V}")"
echo "=========================================="
printf "${FOO}" | wc -c
printf "${FOO}" | od -bc -tu1 -w24
printf "${FOO}" | base32 | tr -d "="
echo "Correct or at least wanted result!"
echo "------------------------------------------"
printf '%s' "${FOO}" | wc -c
printf '%s' "${FOO}" | od -bc -tu1 -w24
printf '%s' "${FOO}" | base32 | tr -d "="
echo "------------------------------------------"
printf '%b' "${FOO}" | wc -c
printf '%b' "${FOO}" | od -bc -tu1 -w24
printf '%b' "${FOO}" | base32 | tr -d "="
echo "------------------------------------------"
printf "%s" "${FOO}" | wc -c
printf "%s" "${FOO}" | od -bc -tu1 -w24
printf "%s" "${FOO}" | base32 | tr -d "="
echo "------------------------------------------"
printf "%b" "${FOO}" | wc -c
printf "%b" "${FOO}" | od -bc -tu1 -w24
printf "%b" "${FOO}" | base32 | tr -d "="
```

I get this output from it:

```
bytes: "LaPaLaPa\363\""
KV='  BYTES'='LaPaLaPa\363\"'
==========================================
10
0000000 114 141 120 141 114 141 120 141 363 042
          L   a   P   a   L   a   P   a 363   "
         76  97  80  97  76  97  80  97 243  34
0000012
JRQVAYKMMFIGD4ZC
Correct or at least wanted result!
------------------------------------------
11
0000000 114 141 120 141 114 141 120 141 363 134 042
          L   a   P   a   L   a   P   a 363   \   "
         76  97  80  97  76  97  80  97 243  92  34
0000013
JRQVAYKMMFIGD424EI
------------------------------------------
11
0000000 114 141 120 141 114 141 120 141 363 134 042
          L   a   P   a   L   a   P   a 363   \   "
         76  97  80  97  76  97  80  97 243  92  34
0000013
JRQVAYKMMFIGD424EI
------------------------------------------
11
0000000 114 141 120 141 114 141 120 141 363 134 042
          L   a   P   a   L   a   P   a 363   \   "
         76  97  80  97  76  97  80  97 243  92  34
0000013
JRQVAYKMMFIGD424EI
------------------------------------------
11
0000000 114 141 120 141 114 141 120 141 363 134 042
          L   a   P   a   L   a   P   a 363   \   "
         76  97  80  97  76  97  80  97 243  92  34
0000013
JRQVAYKMMFIGD424EI
```

Ok, so why I don't just use the first result if that seems to work?

Well one reason is `printf` should not be used without a `FORMAT` string I guess and because there should be some `FORMAT` string for `printf` which seems to be used by default(?) and does accomplish what I want?
The other reason is I had other ByteStrings where I got errors ONLY when I didn't provide any `FORMAT` string (`printf: ...: invalid format character`) and I think this happened when there were percentage characters inside the ByteString but I am not sure at this point and I do not have examples right not unfortunately which reproduce this.
So I have to provide a FORMAT string to be safe, right? But as you can see when I try some other FORMAT strings I get the wrong result for this example!?!?

So in case there is a `FORMAT` string which just works for any case then I could just use this one but I did not find any default so far?

So what is the default `FORMAT` for the printf bash builtin function?

EDIT
The title of my question is what was answered in good detail so thanks for that first of all. I already learned to check the synopsis carefully so I could have figured that out myself. The problem is a bit more complex in that I have this mix of octal escapes and backslash escapes together. But if I use double quotes somewhere to get the ByteString interpolated automatically then this would interpolate the octal values not correct in the sense that it would just escapes the FIRST of the THREE digits. So the two characters or bytes inside the double quotes `"\363\""` would become `363"` so I would then get out 4 characters / bytes of it 3,6,3 and a double quote and NOT the character with octal value 363 followed by a double quote! So I guess my question (now that I know more about printf and that the upstream puts out non standard ByteStrings) is now which is the best / fail safe strategy now? Wouldn't it make sense to convert / transform the octal escape sequences maybe myself somehow first? And then let bash (I assume it is bash doing the interpolation between double quotes "" ?) do the interpolation of the remaining backslash escapes? Or how would I do this in two steps then? The strategy I tried with printf '%s' or '%b' in the script did not workout in the end so far and I don't now how to make this work.

So to sum it up I guess the right strategy here would then be to reduce the value by replacing octal escapes with corresponding characters OR maybe standard backslash escapes in a first step so that the result of this can than further get inerpolated by bash itself when put between double qutes? Is this right? If yes how can this be done?

EDIT2
As suggested by Aaron in the comments I tried to come up with a solution which is to use the `printf` `FORMAT` string `%b` to get the octal escape sequences converted to characters and then right after that step do the transformation of the result where I replace all occurrences of `\"` with a single double quote `"`.

```sh
printf '%b' "${FOO}" | sed 's|\\"|"|g' | wc -c
printf '%b' "${FOO}" | sed 's|\\"|"|g' | od -bc -tu1 -w24
printf '%b' "${FOO}" | sed 's|\\"|"|g' | base32 | tr -d "="
```

```
10
0000000 114 141 120 141 114 141 120 141 363 042
          L   a   P   a   L   a   P   a 363   "
         76  97  80  97  76  97  80  97 243  34
0000012
JRQVAYKMMFIGD4ZC
```

This seems to work as I get the result that is correct in this case.

I hope this produces the correct results in every case as well...

Comment: There's no default format, when you only provide a single parameter it's used as format with no parameters (or is it a single parameter that is the empty string?). For instance if you want to output the text "%d" you'll need to use `printf '%s' '%d'`, because using `printf '%d'` would output "0" (the empty string formatted as a number). Using `%s` as your default format would I believe work without problem

Comment: The input ByteString value is 10 bytes long for which I want to calculate the base32 value. It does not work with '%s' as FORMAT unfortunately. I then get a different result and the value is somewhere not processed correctly because somewhere an additional character is added and the value is then 11 bytes instead of 10 bytes.

Comment: Sorry, I knew I should have read your question in more details but the wall of code/wall of result was hard to read and I was eager to dispel the confusion around the default format. I now understand you want to have both `\363` and `\"` interpreted as single characters. As far as I can tell your problem is that `\"` isn't an escape sequence outside of the context of double-quoted text, i.e. `"\""` contains a single character but `'\"'` always is parsed as two characters, and if you wanted a single one you'd simply write `'"'`. To interpret `\363` using `%b` rather than `%s` is the way to go

Comment: So what I mean is that if you can't change your upstream to stop writing `\"` when it means `"`, you might have to make the `\" -> "` transformation yourself as it is not standard

Comment: Re your edit : to me you should use `%b` as a format to `printf` in order to display the octal sequence `\363` as a single character, it's its explicit role. However you will need to handle `\"` separately as it actually isn't an escape sequence. I intend to edit my answer to address that since it currently doesn't fully answer your question but I'd like to find some source concerning the status of `\"` as an escape sequence and it's proving difficult. I'll probably come back to it tomorrow

Comment: Actually I already tried a similar solution at some point. I used `tr -d '\'` right before calculating the base32 value. Although it worked out I was still wondering if this is a good solution in the sense that I did not want to introduce some custom strategy not knowing if this would lead to errors or wrong results in case of other ByteStrings comming from upstream. And now thinking more about it, I should probably replace only exactly the combination of the two characters and not all backslashes.

Comment: This strategy produced the correct results on my testcases so far. `printf '%b' "$V" | sed 's|\\"|"|g' | base32 | tr -d '='`. What I did not try but should work also is to prepare the `$V` variable such that every occurrence of the two characters `\"` gets replaced by the octal escape equivalent. So replace every `\"` with `\042` (OCTAL 42 = DECIMAL 34 = `"` = double quote character).

Comment: Hey, unless we find something that natively interprets both `\"` and octal escape sequences as escape sequences but doesn't interpret '%x' as a format specifier  I think your current strategy is the correct one. Mapping `\x` to octal escape sequences would still be custom mapping for the sake of a single character and you'd have to distinguish between backslashes followed by a single char and octal sequences to avoid mapping `\343` to `\06343` (063 is the octal code for ascii char '3')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf` can't be used without a format string : when you call it with a single argument, that argument is parsed as the format.

Consider its synopsys in `man bash` :

> printf [-v var] format [arguments]

It's the arguments list that is optional, not the format.

`man bash` goes on saying that plain characters found in the format string are copied as-is to the output stream, which is why you can use `printf 'message'` as you would `echo 'message'`.

However, it also adds that it will identify character escape sequences to convert them before printing (which is similar to what `echo -e` would do) and most importantly, "format character sequences" (`%X` substrings) which it will replace by the (possibly transformed) additional parameters, or a default value if there is no parameter left to consume.

This is the reason why you shouldn't `printf "$message"` : your `$message` might contain sequences of characters that will be interpreted by `printf`.

If you want to print a message as-is, you will want to use `printf '%s' "$message"`, where `%s` is the format specifier that asks `printf` to ouput the (text) parameter as text (so, to output it unmodified).